# Telegram like widget/dialog shadow?

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

I'm not newbie in Qt framework, but would like to have my app to have [Telegram](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop) like shadow effect, can somebody guide me.
PS
Is there anybody that analyzed `UI` part of `Telegram source code`. I've tried but it seems confusing. Can you help me?

Comment: What shadow effect?

Comment: @ypnos For example when you press `dropdown-menu` there appears sliding and shadow effects on right on desktop version.